# Error 1064:You have an error in your SQL syntax - mysql select query

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC limit 1 ) where LANGUAGE =  'ENGLISH' group by su.username ASC LIMIT 0, 500' at line 4

```
SELECT 
  su.*,COUNT(hrr.ENGLISHASSIGNEE) as userCount 
FROM systemuser su LEFT JOIN 
     hansardreporterroster hrr ON  su.username = hrr.ENGLISHASSIGNEE  
     AND hrr.DAY = (SELECT DAY 
                    FROM `hansardreporterroster` 
                    Where ENGLISHASSIGNEE 
                       IS NOT NULL 
                    group by day DESC limit 1 ) 
where LANGUAGE =  'ENGLISH' group by su.username ASC;
```

Comment: group by day "DESC"?

Comment: @SalmanA yes -  group by day "DESC"

Comment: I am stumped. How do you group something descending? You can order something descending but group? Did you try removing desc from both group bys?

Comment: desc or asc are options in an order by clause not in a group by clause..From 8.0..

Comment: write an order by DAY  DESC  behing group it is illigal

Comment: @SalmanA - Before 8.0 in absence of an ORDER BY clause the result has been ordered by the GROUP BY columns and ASC/DESC could be used to modify the order.

Comment: @SalmanA Issue is fixed. i removed ASC end of the query. not it is working. Thank you for your support

Comment: @P.Salmon Issue is fixed. i removed ASC end of the query. not it is working. Thank you for your support

Answer (score 2):

`GROUP BY ... DESC` is not permitted any more since MySQL 8.0.13. Compare the docs for [5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

> ```
> [WHERE where_condition]
> [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}
>   [ASC | DESC], ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
> [HAVING where_condition]
> ```
>
> [...]
>   MySQL extends the GROUP BY clause so that you can also specify `ASC` and
>   `DESC` after columns named in the clause. However, this syntax is
>   deprecated. To produce a given sort order, provide an ORDER BY clause.

and [8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

> ```
> [WHERE where_condition]
> [GROUP BY {col_name | expr | position}, ... [WITH ROLLUP]]
> [HAVING where_condition]
> ```
>
> [...] Prior to MySQL 8.0.13, MySQL supported a nonstandard syntax
>   extension that permitted explicit `ASC` or `DESC` designators for `GROUP BY`
>   columns. MySQL 8.0.12 and later supports `ORDER BY` with grouping
>   functions so that use of this extension is no longer necessary.

Actually it never really made sense.

You though probably just want `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT DAY 
FROM `hansardreporterroster` 
Where ENGLISHASSIGNEE IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY day DESC limit 1
```

Or `MAX()`

```
SELECT MAX(DAY)
FROM `hansardreporterroster` 
Where ENGLISHASSIGNEE IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Issue i f fixed . i removed ASC end of the query. thank you all for support